# Why consecutive calls to update with empty dict in RequestContext.__init__?

Tags: python, django, dictionary

The following is the implementation of the [`__init__`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/context.py#L226-L237) method in `RequestContext`

```
def __init__(self, request, dict_=None, processors=None, use_l10n=None, use_tz=None, autoescape=True):
        super(RequestContext, self).__init__(
            dict_, use_l10n=use_l10n, use_tz=use_tz, autoescape=autoescape)
        self.request = request
        self._processors = () if processors is None else tuple(processors)
        self._processors_index = len(self.dicts)

        # placeholder for context processors output
        self.update({})

        # empty dict for any new modifications
        # (so that context processors don't overwrite them)
        self.update({})
```

As you can see, it calls `self.update({})` consecutively without any operation in between.

While the comment preceding each call mentioned what it's doing, I still failed to see the difference because without the comment, it looks like this:

```
def __init__(self, request, dict_=None, processors=None, use_l10n=None, use_tz=None, autoescape=True):
            super(RequestContext, self).__init__(
                dict_, use_l10n=use_l10n, use_tz=use_tz, autoescape=autoescape)
            self.request = request
            self._processors = () if processors is None else tuple(processors)
            self._processors_index = len(self.dicts)

            self.update({})
            self.update({})
```

Isn't the second call not redundant?

Comment: That depends on the `update()` method, but most likely it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Summary

The *update()* method pushes the new dict on the stack of dictionaries.  That means that two *update* calls will push two dictionaries.

As the comment explains, the first dict pushed is a placeholder for context processors output, and the second dict pushed isolates any modifications from the rest of the stack.

### Details

This is easier to understand if you look at the [source code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/template/context/#Context):

```
def update(self, other_dict):
        "Pushes other_dict to the stack of dictionaries in the Context"
        if not hasattr(other_dict, '__getitem__'):
            raise TypeError('other_dict must be a mapping (dictionary-like) object.')
        if isinstance(other_dict, BaseContext):
            other_dict = other_dict.dicts[1:].pop()
        return ContextDict(self, other_dict)
```

### Core Issue

I think the point of confusion is that a regular *dict.update()* is [idempotent](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/idempotency.html), so doing it a second time is pointless.  In contrast, each consecutive call to *Context.update()* pushes an additional dictionary on the stack, so doing it a second time is useful.